# How to ignore empty pipes in CHILD process?

Tags: c, pipe, fdopen

I am using a subroutine named `read_from_pipe` in my `child` process as below to read whatever is in the pipe and display it:

```
void read_from_pipe(int fileDescriptr)
{
    FILE *stream;
    int c;
    if (fileDesc_Is_Valid(fileDescriptr) == TRUE)
    {
        stream = fdopen(fileDescriptr, "r");
        while ((c = fgetc(stream)) != EOF)
            putchar(c);                                     
        fclose(stream);
    }
    else                                                     
        perror("Reading from pipe failed -->");
}
```

`fileDesc_Is_Valid` is another subroutine which checks the existance of file descriptor.

The problem is that because I have used `waitpid(pid, &status, 0);` statement in my `parent` to wait for `child` to finish off its tasks, the compiler gets stuck in the first cold run at `while` loop when pipe is actually empty. How can I `AND` another condition in my `while` to let compiler simply ignore empty pipes?

Comment: Search for `SIGPIPE`, and tutorials on how to handle (or ignore) signals.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg hmmm... Thats sounds more complicated than what I initially thought. Is that the only option I 've got?

Comment: No, you can use `signalfd()` + `poll()` (or similar)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's actually very simple, you just need to ignore the `SIGPIPE` signal, and it's done with a single function-call:

```
signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
```

When the pipe is empty, instead of raising the `SIGPIPE` signal, reading from the pipe will return an end-of-file value (the underlying `read` system-call will return `0`).

Comment: @Bababarghi Just add the line early during your applications initialization code.

Comment: Must everyone be spoon-fed? Literally copy-and-paste the line of code he's given you, throw it at the top of `main()`, and remain blissfully ignorant. Otherwise, you can read more about signals and understand how they affect your program, and how you can control them.